# Working with piecewise answer in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Sometimes MatLab gives me answer in `piecewise` notation, like this:

> piecewise([1 < x, 0], [abs(x) < 1, -(log(x - 1) - 1)*(x - 1)])

Is it possible to take any pair from answer?

For example, take second pair from previous answer (will be `-(log(x - 1) - 1)*(x - 1)`).

Comment: are you using Mupad?

Comment: I have this toolbox, but I working with Symbolic Toolbox in this case.